# Algorithms as fractals

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, fractals

Recursion utilizes some self similar nature of an object (some representation of the given problem) to produce some quantitative measure (output) on the object through some algorithm (utilizing the self similar nature).

Can one represent algorithms as fractals (such a representation is not possible is not obvious nor how the representation should be if one exists) of some measurable information of the object the algorithm works on?

Has the tools used in the study of fractals provided any illuminating examples for lower or upper bounds for recursive complexity of algorithms?

I am looking for examples and references along the lines of whether algorithms can be treated as fractals and tools about fractals can be used to prove results about algorithms.

**just added** Would we be compelled to redefine some essential property of Sierpinski triangle if Walsh Transform or Sierpinski triangle transform is shown to be fully linear?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walsh_matrix

Comment: IIUC, you are asking: "has tools used in the study of fractals been used in proving lower/upper-bounds on the complexity of algorithms?". You may want to expand more on why you think that is likely and explain the first paragraph in more detail. Many fractals are recursively defined and have self-similar structure but I don't think one implies the other: recursive definition of an object doesn't mean it is a fractal and a fractal doesn't need to be recursively defined. I don't see how information comes into play here.

Comment: By the way, I am not sure what you mean by "recursive complexity of algorithms". Do you mean something other than the usual notions of complexity of algorithms? ps: I edited the question a bit to make it easier to read, feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: JeffE's answer seems to be close to why such a framework may not be possible.

Comment: I am not sure how that follows from Jeff's answer. ps: More generally the real RAM model is one of the approaches to computable analysis. In the opinion of many experts in computable analysis it is not a very good model, particularly from the practical perspective, as it lacks the ability to deal with limits which is essential for analysis and the model doesn't correspond to how we deal with real numbers in practice.  There are papers by Ker-I Ko, Mark Braverman, ... on computability/complexity of fractals. Btw, ch.9 of Weirauch book has a comparision of different models if you are interested.

Comment: 'close' is a relative term here. I take the cue from 'almost every interesting fractal is uncomputable'. However including your feedback seems to say something about the question as well.

Comment: there is some research linking fractals to hardness of [SAT instances](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4375/which-sat-problems-are-easy/16431)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Blum, Shub, and Smale proved that [membership in the Mandelbrot set is undecidable](http://books.google.com/books?id=zxtrVqUP-AwC&lpg=PA55&pg=PA55#v=onepage&q&f=true) in the [Real RAM model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_RAM) of computation (known in [some upstart circles](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/2124/111) as the [BSS model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%E2%80%93Shub%E2%80%93Smale_machine)).

The high-level argument is one sentence long: Any Real RAM computable set is the countable union of semi-algebraic sets, so its boundary has Hausdorff dimension 1, but the boundary of the Mandelbrot set has Hausdorff dimension 2.  By the same argument, **almost every interesting fractal is uncomputable** in the real-RAM model.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look to the work of Lutz, Mayordomo, Hitchcock, Gu et al. on [Effective dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_dimension):

*... In mathematics, effective dimension is a modification of Hausdorff dimension and other fractal dimensions which places it in a computability theory setting ...*

I found interesting (though I'm not an expert) E. Mayordomo's introductive video ["Effective Fractal Dimension in Computational Complexity and Algorithmic Information Theory"](http://sms.cam.ac.uk/media/1254201) (or the related [paper](http://webdiis.unizar.es/~elvira/publicaciones/efdait.pdf)).

See also: [John M. Hitchcock, Jack H. Lutz, Elvira Mayordomo, "The Fractal Geometry of Complexity Classes"](http://www.cs.uwyo.edu/~jhitchco/papers/fgcc.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

An application of fractals in document analysis has been proposed in

Tang, Y.Y.; Hong Ma; Xiaogang Mao; Dan Liu; Suen, C.Y., "A new approach to document analysis based on modified fractal signature," Document Analysis and Recognition, 1995., Proceedings of the Third International Conference on , vol.2, no., pp.567,570 vol.2, 14-16 Aug 1995
doi: 10.1109/ICDAR.1995.601960

Here is the abstract:

The proposed approach is based on modified fractal signature. Instead of the time-consuming traditional approaches (top-down and bottom-up approaches) where iterative operations are necessary to break a document into blocks to extract its geometric (layout) structure, this new approach can divide a document into blocks in only one step. This approach can be used to process documents with high geometrical complexity. Experiments have been conducted to prove the proposed new approach for document processing

Two years later, they published an extended journal version:

Yuan Y. Tang, Hong Ma, Dihua Xi, Xiaogang Mao, Ching Y. Suen, "Modified Fractal Signature (MFS): A New Approach to Document Analysis for Automatic Knowledge Acquisition," IEEE Transactions on Knowledge and Data Engineering, vol. 9, no. 5, pp. 747-762, September-October, 1997

[Here](http://www.sc.ehu.es/ccwgrrom/transparencias/articulos-alumnos-doct-2002/andoni/00634753.pdf) is the latter paper.

Answer (score 2):

part of the challenge in this area is there seems not to be a strict formal/mathematical definition of the term ["fractal"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal). originally as coined by [Mandelbrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benoit_Mandelbrot) in 1975 it had an informal geometric interpretation but is now seen as more general, eg applying to misc important mathematical objects created/discovered before unifying principles/properties of fractals were recognized, such as [Cantor dust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_dust#Cantor_dust) or the [Sierpinsky triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle) or even the [Weierstrauss function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).

of course as in these examples an algorithm to draw fractals has fractal complexity properties. however there seems to be a much deeper connection between fractals and algorithms (maybe fundamental?) as uncovered in the links between fractal computations and undecidability (maybe two faces of the same phenomena?).

one alternative is to consider the closely related [iterated function systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system). eg try

- [Fractal geometry, Turing machines, and divide-and-conquer recurrences](https://eudml.org/doc/92487) [[pdf]](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ITA/ITA_1994__28_3-4/ITA_1994__28_3-4_405_0/ITA_1994__28_3-4_405_0.pdf)
  S. Dube,
  Informatique
  théorique
  et
  Applications/Theoietical
  Informaties
  and
  Applications
  (vol.
  28,
  no
  3-4,
  1994,
  p.
  405-423)

> These
>   results
>   show
>   that
>   for
>   every
>   Turing
>   machine
>   there
>   exists
>   a
>   fractal
>   set
>   which
>   can
>   be
>   viewed,
>   in
>   a
>   certain
>   sense,
>   as
>   geometrically
>   encoding
>   the
>   complement
>   of
>   the
>   language
>   accepted
>   by
>   the
>   machine.
>   One
>   can
>   build
>   a
>   fractal-based
>   geometrical
>   model
>   of
>   computation
>   which
>   is
>   computationally
>   universal.
>   Secondly
>   we
>   survey
>   the
>   results
>   which
>   show
>   how
>   fractal
>   geometry
>   can
>   be
>   fruitfully
>   used
>   to
>   solve
>   divide-and-conquer
>   recurrences.
>   A
>   recursive
>   algorithm
>   possesses
>   temporal
>   self-similarity
>   and
>   there
>   is
>   a
>   natural
>   connection
>   with
>   spatial
>   self-similar
>   objects
>   (fractal
>   images).
>   This
>   approach
>   yields
>   a
>   new
>   and
>   gênerai
>   way
>   of
>   solving
>   such
>   divide-and-conquer
>   récurrences.

- [Undecidable
  Problems
  in
  Fractal
  Geometry](http://www.complex-systems.com/pdf/07-6-2.pdf)
  S. Dube, Complex
  Systems
  7
  (1993)
  423-444

> In this
>   paper, a
>   relationship
>   between
>   the
>   classical
>   theory
>   of
>   computation
>   and
>   fractal
>   geometry
>   is
>   established.
>   Iterated Function
>   Systems are
>   used
>   as
>   tools
>   to
>   define
>   fractals.
>   It
>   is
>   shown
>   that
>   two
>   questions about
>   Iterated
>   Function
>   Systems are
>   undecidable:
>   to test
>   if the
>   attractor
>   of
>   a
>   given Iterated
>   Function
>   System
>   and
>   a given
>   line
>   segment intersect
>   and to
>   test
>   if a given
>   Iterated
>   Function System
>   is
>   totally
>   disconnected.